# Creating a class instance from type

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection, activator

I'm trying to create an instance of a class that I can add to a list in a generic way..

I know the `type` of class that needs to be made and i've been able to make an `object` of the class using the code below but I have not found a way to create a cast that will allow me to add this to a list.. any ideas?

T is the same as objType

```
public static List<T> LoadList(string fileName, Type objType)
{
    List<T> objList = new List<T>();
    object o = Activator.CreateInstance(objType);
    objList.Add((**o.GetType()**)o);
    return objList;
}
```

if theres a better way of doing this too im open to ideas :)

Comment: Is <type> the same as objType?

Comment: yes zach sorry for confusion I'll change it either way..

Comment: Given that, I suggest using type constraints.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the non-generic API:

```
((IList)objList).Add(o);
```

I'm also assuming that `type` is a generic type-parameter; just to say: `type` is confusing for this; `T` or `TSomethingSpecific` would be more idiomatic.

Also: this line needs fixing:

```
List<type> objList = new List<type>(); // <=== not new List<Object>
```

Comment: well that was surprisingly simple.. thanks! sorry for the confusion on the list line i forgot to change it in my post above (Object is the class type in my list.. its different from System.Object and not my choice of name!)

Comment: @Sayse ouch. I would keel-haul whoever made that naming choice ;p

Answer (score 2):

Given that `<type>` is the same as `objType`, I'd suggest dropping the reflection and using the [where T : new() type constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
public static List<T> LoadList(string fileName) 
    where T : new()
{
    List<T> objList = new List<T>();
    objList.add(new T());
    return objList;
}
```

**Edit:**

If `objType` is a subclass of `T`, then I think something along these lines should work:

```
public static List<TListType, T> LoadList(string fileName)
    where T : TListType, new()
{
    List<TListType> objList = new List<TListType>();
    objList.add(new T());
    return objList;
}
```

Comment: I'll have a look into this way zach.. I'm unfamiliar with the 'where' attribute..

Comment: @Sayse: They're pretty helpful because it means calls to the method or instances of the class can only have types that meet those minimum specifications.  So you can call methods, etc that the minimum specification provide.

Comment: Did you mean to declare `LoadList<T>` ?

Comment: It looks like in the edited question, `T` is not the same as `objType` - presumably a sub-type or concrete-type; so I'm not sure this would work.

Comment: As Marc has said this does not look suitable for my situation but I'll keep it in mind :)

Comment: @Marc hmm...true. Answer updated for `T` not equal to `objType`.

Comment: @Sayse Edited with another possibility.

Answer (score 1):

You could user Zach Johnson's suggestion with the `where` constraint as it eliminates a duplicate specification of the type. However if the signature is set in stone, you could get by with a simple `as` cast, like:

```
public List<T> LoadList<T>(Type objType) where T : class
{
  List<T> objList = new List<T>();
  T item = (Activator.CreateInstance(objType) as T);
  objList.Add(item);
  return objList;
}
```

This also needs a where restriction, because in order to cast to a type, that type must be a  reference type (aka class).

Comment: To make things even more fun, T is a base class and the item needs to be one of the inherited items, I've used Marc Gravells answer in my project but I'm definately going to spend time looking into 'where' :)

Comment: This will work in that case too, because `as` only changes the type of the reference, so it can be added to the collection. The actual type of the object is determined by the `objType`